# Mount reactjs component on ajax success

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to mount a react component using jquery to a bootstrap modal body and then open the modal after a successful ajax request, however I cannot seem to get the react component to load. This is what I have so far:

After success I am calling the assignModal function, I am inside a parent react component.

```
assignModal: function(){
 $('.assign-modal-body').html(<Cortex.VulnerabilityList.AssignModal parent={this}/>);
 $("#vuln-assign-modal").modal('show');}
```

And here is the react component

```
Cortex.VulnerabilityList.AssignModal = React.createClass({
 componentDidMount: function() {
 console.log("Component mounted")
},

 render: function() {
  return (
   <h1>Hello</h1>
  )
 }
});
```

Comment: `ReactDOM.render(<Cortex.VulnerabilityList.AssignModal />, document.querySelector('.assign-modal-body') )`

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you're going to have trouble if you try to use both jQuery and React to manipulate the DOM. If it's at all an option for you, get rid of jQuery and fully embrace React's declarative programming paradigm.

But maybe you have jQuery widgets you want to use. In that case, try and design your app in such a way that jQuery never writes to the DOM within your React tree.

So a few options:

1. **Use jQuery and React, but separately** - Have your React app descending from some root `<div>` and have your modal in a sibling `<div>`. Then just use jQuery and normal HTML to render your modal without involving React.
2. **Stop using jQuery** - Use React to manage your modal. So instead of responding to `assignModal` by setting the innerHTML of a DOM element with jQuery, simply set some global state to `showModal = true` and in the render method of the modal `if (!showModal) return null` or something like that. I [wrote a post](https://medium.com/@david.gilbertson/modals-in-react-f6c3ff9f4701) about this recently.